# what is the difference between native c++ compiler and .net c++ compiler?

Tags: c++, .net, native

what is the difference between native c++ compiler and .net c++ compiler? Just for curiosity one of my friend asked me this question.

Comment: ".net c++ compiler" doesn't mean anything.  The Microsoft C++ compiler supports a language extension called C++/CLI.  Enabled with the /clr compile option.  C++/CLI allows writing code that runs on the .NET Framework that can easily interop with native C++ code without having to use the pinvoke marshaller.  The language itself only resembles C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general .net C++ compiler is a compiler that can compile C++/CLI code and generates intermediate object code.
While native c++ compiler is a compiler that knows nothing about C++/CLI and designed to compile C++ code.

Comment: ok thank you this has certainly given me a great help to answer